# Creating ListView from a Collection Set

Tags: java, android, android-listview, set

I am currently developing a soundboard with the ability to add a sound as a favorite. I have a favorites tab and am working on adding sounds to a ListView when clicked. I did some research and came across a post suggesting to use a `Set` when avoiding duplicate items. In my application class I have a global variable: `public Set<String> favorite_list = new TreeSet<String>();`. In my ListViewActivity I have

```
ArrayList favorite_list = (ArrayList) appState.favorite_list;
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.favorites, favorite_list));
```

Whenever I click the Favorites Tab, the app force closes. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks, Justin

Edit: LogCat

```
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{vartanian.android.epicmealtimepro/vartanian.android.epicmealtimepro.Favorites}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.TreeSet cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1797)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:682)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:346)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:150)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:540)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.TreeSet cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at vartanian.android.epicmealtimepro.Favorites.onCreate(Favorites.java:27)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-05 21:25:12.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5485):     ... 18 more
```

Application Class:

```
public class Data extends Application {
     public Set<String> favorite_list = new TreeSet<String>();
}
```

ListView Class:

```
public class Favorites extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Data appState = ((Data)this.getApplication());
        if(appState.favorite_list.isEmpty() == true){
            appState.favorite_list.add("None");
        }
        ArrayList favorite_list = (ArrayList) appState.favorite_list;
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.favorites, favorite_list));
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your crash log from LogCat?

Comment: It seems you are not initializing the collections. If you could post more detail will help us to understand it properly.

Comment: @Naved I initialized the set with: `public Set<String> favorite_list = new TreeSet<String>();`

Comment: You can't cast a TreeSet to an ArrayList - they are incompatible types. You're going to have to convert the set to an array. I'd create an Arraylist, then add the members of the set to it.

Comment: @MoKargas I do that with: `ArrayList favorite_list = (ArrayList) appState.favorite_list;
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.favorites, favorite_list));` I updated the post with both classes

Comment: Justin, that's not a conversion, that's what is called a "cast". Since the Treeset isn't the same type or subtype as ArrayList, that is going to always fail.

Comment: @MoKargas Ahh ok. I did not know that. I am still learning lol. Is a Set even plausible in this situation? If so, what type should I use?

Comment: If you're still learning, I'd review some Java before Android. A set is plausible for this situation, though you could probably get away with an `ArrayList` if you're careful with it. I haven't done much with sets, but if you read the documentation, both ArrayList and Sets inherit `AbstractCollection`. So `ArrayList favorite_list = new ArrayList(appState.favorite_list)`, should theoretically work

Comment: If you need Set (for some reason) and you want to convert it to the List, you can use favorite_list.addAll(appState.favorite_list);

Comment: @MoKargas That worked! I really appreciate the help and next time I will read the documentation more carefully.